# Any command in mysql equivalent to Oracle's autotrace for performance turning

Tags: mysql, performance

In oracle sql plus, while doing performance testing, I would do

```
set autotrace traceonly:
```

which would display the query plan and statistics without printing the actual results. Is there anything equivalent in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no equivalent available in MySQL, at least not in the community edition.

MySQL does not implement the kind of "instrumentation" that Oracle has in its code; so there's no equivalent to an event 10046 trace.

You can preface your SELECT statement with the `EXPLAIN` keyword, and that will produce output with information about the execution plan that MySQL would use to run the statement, but that's just an estimate, and not a monitoring of the actual execution.

You can also enable the slow query log on the server, to capture SQL statements that take longer than `long_query_time` seconds to execute, but that really only identifies the long running queries. That would give you the SQL text, along with elapsed time and a count of rows examined.

Answer (score -1):

To get the query plan, just add `EXPLAIN` to the beginning of a `SELECT` query.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table
```

It also estimates the number of rows to be read if that's what statistics you're talking about.