# Is there alternative to "autotrace traceonly" on Apache Drill?

Tags: sql, sqlplus, apache-drill

I'm new to Apache Drill.

For performance testing purpose, I'm trying to measure the time to execute a query. And also I do not need to print the executed result.

In Oracle SQL Plus, there is `set autotrace traceonly`. This setting feature is the following(quoting from the [oracle web site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/autotrac.htm)):

> Similar to SET AUTOTRACE ON, but suppresses the printing of the user's query output, if any. If STATISTICS is enabled, query data is still fetched, but not printed.

In Apache Drill's sqlline, I got the error like the following: `Error: PARSE ERROR: Encountered "traceonly" at line 1, column 15...`

Do you have any ideas for alternatives?

Thanks,

p.s.

I also read this answered question.  [Any command in mysql equivalent to Oracle's autotrace for performance turning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531333/any-command-in-mysql-equivalent-to-oracles-autotrace-for-performance-turning)
Unfortunately, it doesn't work on Apache Drill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your query(s) in a text file (e.g. query.sql), then run sqlline and forward the output to /dev/null:

```
bin/sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=localhost:2181 -f query.sql > /dev/null
```

It will still display some data, but only minimal:

```
1/1          select * from cp.`employee.json`;
1,155 rows selected (0.65 seconds)
Closing: org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl
apache drill 1.4.0 
"say hello to my little drill"
```

Comment: Thank you for your post! It works. Without creating sql file is the best of best for me, but your solution is still wonderful. Thanks.